# Hide (and show) links when div is dynamically resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to resize a div when a user decides to hide (or show) particular content. For example, I have a contents page (https://jsfiddle.net/4b1g5jp9/1/), when a user clicks `hide`, I want the div to resize accordingly, hiding all contents except the actual **Contents** title.

Also, the 'Show' link should only show if the content is actually hidden and vice versa.

I have tried to adapt some JS based on a similar issue I found online and tried the following approach:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function toggle() {
                var ele = document.getElementById("contents-list");
                if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                    ele.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    ele.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

But the above achieves nothing. Any advice/solution would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only want the 'Contents' title to be visible, how is the user supposed to un-hide the remaining contents?

Comment: Assuming that jQuery is ok. Check this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4b1g5jp9/10/

Comment: just wait sir i think i can help you.

Comment: sir if you need according then try this link https://jsfiddle.net/bjayanta/hf6kfpkp/7/

Comment: if it is work than Knock me please

Comment: sir you can try http://jsfiddle.net/bjayanta/hf6kfpkp/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the event's target we can determine what to show/hide. 
If we do it that way, we can use this multiple times on a single page without it messing with each other.

Also, I've used toggle() which basically does the if() you had in your code statement for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/qhb8ccob/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.toggle').click( function(event) {
   $(event.target).parents('.contents-list').find('ul').toggle();
   var newText = $(event.target).text() === '[Hide]' ? '[Show]' : '[Hide]';
    $(event.target).text(newText);
  });
});
```

```css
.contents-list{
    width: 300px;
   
    background-color: #f4f6f9;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b4b5;
}

.contents-list ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#contents-list ul li{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.contents-list ul li a{
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.contents-list a:visited { 
    text-decoration: none; color:blue; 
}
.contents-list ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.centerContents{
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents-list">
  <div class="centerContents"><b> Contents </b> 
    <a class="toggle" href="#hideContents">[Hide]</a>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ1"> 1.  What is Mobility? </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ2"> 2.  Why Mobility is important </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ3"> 3.  Other </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="contents-list">
  <div class="centerContents"><b> Contents </b> 
    <a class="toggle" href="#hideContents">[Hide]</a>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ1"> 1.  What is Mobility? </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ2"> 2.  Why Mobility is important </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#jumpQ3"> 3.  Other </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see via your fiddle that your approach works and it is exactly what I am looking for. However, I cannot seem to emulate the results, is there something I am missing? https://jsfiddle.net/3bdq06g7/1/

Comment: Yeah, pay close attention to the ID's and Class names. 
Since I made it to be used with more than one panel, I have changed the ID's you use to Classes. 

ID's should be unique, classes can be added multiple times. 
In the jquery code, an ID and Class is targeted like in CSS; with a "#" for ID and a "." for classes.

So change <div id="contents-list"> to <div class="contents-list"> and it should work in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

**Use that structure as your HTML:**

```
<div id="contents-list">
    <ul>
        <li id="centerContents"><b> Contents </b> 
            <a class="hideLinks" href="#">[Hide]</a>
            <a class="showLinks" href="#">[Show]</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li> <a href="#jumpQ1"> 1.  What is Mobility? </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#jumpQ2"> 2.  Why Mobility is important </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#jumpQ3"> 3.  Other </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#contents-list ul li a.hideLinks").click(function(){
        $("ul.submenu").css("display", "none");
    });

    $("#contents-list ul li a.showLinks").click(function(){
        $("ul.submenu").css("display", "block");
    });
</script>
```

Your jQuery script should be right after the HTML, or near the `</body>` tag. And make sure to call jQuery cdn inside `head` tag: `<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

**NOTE**: You can use `Show()` and `Hide()` functions instead of css display properties. You can read more about those functions [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).